# saving pointer with objectId in Parse.Cloud

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using parse cloud function to some filtering in user table. i have extracted user's objectId and doing some grouping. After that i am having just user's objectId as a string. But now i need to save this objectId as Pointer to the users in another table like in iOS

`PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Post"objectId:@"objectId"];`

Any suggestion to do this in cloud code.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent in JavaScript, for a `PFUser` pointer, would be:

```
 var userPointer = Parse.User.createWithoutData("myObjectId") ;
```

This applies to any other class that extends `Parse.Object`. For example, say that you have a "Foo" class:

```
 var Foo = Parse.Object.extend("Foo");
 var pointerToFoo = Foo.createWithoutData("myObjectId");
```

...will work just as well as:

```
 var Foo = Parse.Object.extend("Foo");
 var pointerToFoo = new Foo();
 pointerToFoo.id = "myObjectId";
```